# change svg title position and font size

Tags: css, svg, tooltip, title

I am using the SVG title tag to create tooltips for multiple svg elements (recs, polygons, etc.).
However, the title element creates a small tooltip which is half covered by the mouse cursor.
I have attempted to use CSS to change the title font size, but to no avail. I have searched for other ways to create the tooltips, but they involve changing the basic layout of my svg (creating multiple g elements for each element on my map).
Is there a way to edit the title style?

Thank you.

This is the complete html file (excluding the basic layer map, as it contains too many characters to be displayed and there is nothing to edit there anyway):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .copier:hover
{
    fill:rgb(32, 43, 228);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

        .copier
{
    fill:rgb(32, 43, 228);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.area:hover
{
    fill:rgb(46, 221, 167);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.area
{
    fill:rgb(46, 221, 167);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.desk:hover
{
    fill:rgb(29, 255, 0);
    fill-opacity:0.6;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.desk
{
    fill:rgb(29, 255, 0);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.redbooks:hover
{
    fill:rgb(255, 0, 0);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.redbooks
{
    fill:rgb(255, 0, 0);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.books:hover
{
    fill:rgb(150, 40, 177);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.books
{
    fill:rgb(150, 40, 177);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

#_x32_1-22_open_university:hover
{
    fill:rgb(235, 255, 0);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

#_x32_1-22_open_university
{
    fill:rgb(235, 255, 0);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

#_x32_1-_reading_literature:hover
{
    fill:rgb(34, 213, 194);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

#_x32_1-_reading_literature
{
    fill:rgb(34, 213, 194);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

#_x32_0_-_textbooks:hover
{
    fill:rgb(128, 128, 128);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

#_x32_0_-_textbooks
{
    fill:rgb(128, 128, 128);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.services:hover
{
    fill:rgb(110, 121, 246);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.services
{
    fill:rgb(110, 121, 246);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.door:hover
{
    fill:rgb(84, 144, 189);
    fill-opacity:0.7;
    pointer-events:all;
}

.door
{
    fill:rgb(84, 144, 189);
    fill-opacity:0.4;
    pointer-events:all;
}

/*Tooltip styles*/
.tooltip
{
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:22pt;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px"
         height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="map">...</g>
        <g id="Borders">
            <polygon class="area" id="Silent_Room" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="165.667,100.836 181.015,91.659
                190.333,83.67 283.455,108.836 283.455,196.781 269.167,203.003 269.167,223.17 143.5,223.17 143.333,106.17 151.833,105.003">
                <title>חדר שקט</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="copier" id="Copier1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="226.667,239.668 226.667,226.668 202,226.668
                202,239.333">
                <title>מדפסות 1 ו-2</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="copier" id="Copier_2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="252.167,226.668 228.167,226.668
                227.833,239.668 252.167,239.333">
                <title>מכונת צילום</title>
            </polygon>
            <polyline class="books" id="_x32_1-22_open_university" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="192.842,261.333
                192.842,264.833 248.917,264.833 248.917,268.333 276.583,268.333 276.583,261.333 192.083,261.167">
                <title>21-22: אוסף האוניברסיטה הפתוחה</title>
            </polyline>
            <rect class="books" id="_x32_1-_reading_literature" x="192.083" y="265.167" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="56.833" height="2.833">
                <title>21: ספרות יפה</title>
            </rect>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x32_0_-_textbooks" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.667,283.5 262.5,283.5
                263.167,287.167 277,287.167 277,279.833 192.592,279.585 191.667,279.833">
                <title>19-20: Textbooks</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_9_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="262.5,287.167 262.5,283.5
                191.667,283.5 192.592,287.167">
                <title>19: 681.31.06 מיצ'-סוף</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_8_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,301.496 277,297.83 191.667,297.83 192.129,301.496   " >
                <title>18: 658.626-681.31.06 מדע</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_7_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,305.163 277,301.497 191.667,301.497 192.129,305.163     " >
                <title>17: 658:577.4-658.58</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_6_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,319.667 277,316 191.667,316 192.129,319.667     " >
                <title>16: 65.012.4-658</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_5_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,324 277,320.333 191.667,320.333 192.129,324     " >
                <title>15: 65.01 Cap-65.012.32</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_4_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,338.167 277,334.5 191.667,334.5 192.129,338.167     " >
                <title>14: 63.001.5-65.01 Bro</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_3_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,341.833 277,338.167 191.667,338.167 192.129,341.833     " >
                <title>13: 621.382 Dan-63(9)(091)</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_2_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,356.667 277,353 191.667,353 192.129,356.667     " >
                <title>12: 62-621.382 Cro</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_1_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="277,360.333 277,356.667 191.667,356.667 192.129,360.333     " >
                <title>11: 591-618</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="desk" id="Computer_Desk_1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="166.167,257.663 166.167,238.329 144.667,237.829 144.667,257.663  " >
                <title>שולחן מחשב</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="desk" id="Computer_Desk_2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="166.167,297.083 166.167,277.75 144.667,277.25 144.667,297.083    " >
                <title>שולחן מחשב</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="desk" id="Computer_Desk_3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="166.167,336.333 166.167,317 144.667,316.5 144.667,336.333    " >
                <title>שולחן מחשב</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="desk" id="Computer_Desk_4" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="166.167,376.5 166.167,357.167 144.667,356.667 144.667,376.5  " >
                <title>שולחן מחשב</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="desk" id="Computer_Desk_5" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="166.167,415.834 166.167,396.5 144.667,396 144.667,415.834    " >
                <title>שולחן מחשב</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x31_0_-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,473.811 276.667,473.311 276.667,476.977 191.833,477.977     " >
                <title>10: 517 גוב-539.2</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x39__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,477.477 276.667,476.977 276.667,480.643 191.833,481.643  " >
                <title>9: 37.018.43-517 איי</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x38__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,491.978 276.667,491.478 276.667,495.144 191.833,496.144  " >
                <title>8: 338.982-37.018.26</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x37__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,495.644 276.667,495.144 276.667,498.81 191.833,499.81    " >
                <title>7: 333.013(73)-338.982</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x36__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,510.686 276.667,510.186 276.667,513.852 191.833,514.852  " >
                <title>6: 327-333(100)</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x35__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,513.269 276.667,512.769 276.667,516.435 191.833,517.435  " >
                <title>5: 301.16-326.1</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x34__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,529.046 276.667,528.546 276.667,532.212 191.833,533.212  " >
                <title>4: 159.953-301.154.12</title>
            </polygon>
            <polygon class="books" id="_x33__-_collection" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="191.833,532.962 276.667,532.462 276.667,536.128 191.833,537.128  " >
                <title>3: 001.4-159.95</title>
            </polygon>
            <rect class="books" id="_x32__-_collection" x="191.833" y="547.48" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="56.5" height="3.167" >
                <title>2: פרויקטים - הנדסאים</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="books" id="_x31__-_collection" x="191.833" y="551.333" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="56.5" height="3.167" >
                <title>1: 7(091)-796.4, קופסאות קיבוץ</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="desk" id="Accessibility_Computer" x="319.25" y="509.125" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="11.75" height="10.5" >
                <title>מחשב נגישות</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="desk" id="Clinical_Psycology" x="319.25" y="496.977" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="11.75" height="10.5" >
                <title>מחשב פסיכולוגיה קלינית</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="services" id="Yaatz" x="319.25" y="468.612" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="21.333" height="19.833" >
                <title>עמדת יעץ</title>
            </rect>
            <polygon class="services" id="Hashala" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="429.666,469.945 384.666,469.945 384.416,456.112 430.082,456.112  " >
                <title>דלפק השאלה</title>
            </polygon>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x33_2_-_red" x="416.416" y="514.684" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>32: 001.81-35(9) שמורים</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x33_1_-_red" x="416.416" y="519.017" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>31: 352-65.012.2 שמורים</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x33_0-red_x2F_Seminars" x="416.416" y="534.601" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>30: 65.012.3-940.2 שמורים, עבודות סמינריוניות</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_9_-_syllabuses" x="416.416" y="538.684" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>29: מקראות</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_8_-_Jounala_articles_Ethiopia" x="416.416" y="554.517" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>28: עיתונות עליית יהודי אתיופיה</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_7_-_syllabuses" x="416.416" y="558.434" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>27: מקראות</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_6_-_dictionaries" x="416.416" y="574.414" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>26: R621.7(02)-R933.44 יעץ</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_5_-_dictionaries" x="416.416" y="578.831" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>25: R3(05)(9)-R621.7 יעץ</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_4_-_dictionaries" x="416.416" y="594.101" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>24: R03=20-R221(048) יעץ</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="redbooks" id="_x32_3_-_dictionaries" x="416.416" y="598.518" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="41.75" height="4.416" >
                <title>23: R000.81-R03:933.44 יעץ</title>
            </rect>
            <polygon class="area" id="Stairs_Down" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="444.667,366.5 444.667,235.833 419.667,235.667 419.667,366.5  " >
                <title>מדרגות לקומת קרקע</title>
            </polygon>
            <polyline class="area" id="Staff_Offices" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="314.168,523.434 314.168,698.499 414.5,698.499 414.5,496.144 362.835,496.144
                362.835,521.226 314.168,521.226     " >
                <title>משרדים</title>
            </polyline>
            <polyline class="desk" id="Guard_Post" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="444.667,196.781 425,196.781 425,220 444.667,220 444.667,195.5    " >
                <title>עמדת שומר</title>
            </polyline>
            <polyline class="door" id="Main_Entrance" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="448.25,192.5 448.25,195.5 479.25,195.5 479.25,192.5 446.751,192.5     " >
                <title>דלת כניסה</title>
            </polyline>
            <polyline class="door" id="Emergency_Exit" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="283,161.67 283,164.67 314,164.67 314,161.67 281.501,161.67   " >
                <title>יציאת חירום</title>
            </polyline>
            <polyline class="door" id="Emergency_Exit_1_" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="278.166,559.143 278.166,562.143 309.166,562.143 309.166,559.143
                276.667,559.143     " >
                <title>יציאת חירום</title>
            </polyline>
            <polygon class="redbooks" id="Staff_Publications" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="419.667,405.917 415.5,405.848
                415.5,376.5 419.667,376.362     " >
                <title>פרסומי סגל</title>
            </polygon>
            <rect class="desk" id="comp_x5F_station_x5F_2" x="277" y="277.25" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="8.685" height="9.917" >
                <title>עמדת מחשב</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="desk" id="comp_x5F_station_x5F_1" x="277" y="351.708" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="8.685" height="9.917">
                <title>עמדת מחשב</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="desk" id="comp_x5F_station_x5F_3" x="498" y="215.042" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="8.685" height="9.917">
                <title>עמדת מחשב</title>
            </rect>
            <rect class="desk" id="comp_x5F_station_x5F_4" x="498" y="199.583" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="8.685" height="9.917">
                <title>עמדת מחשב</title>
            </rect>
            <polygon class="desk" id="comp_x5F_desk_x5F_win" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="395.5,423.499 395.5,413.5
            361.5,412.5 361.5,423.5     " >
                <title>עמדת מחשב</title>
            </polygon>
            <text transform="matrix(0.0047 0.8645 -1 0.0054 90.5835 351.708)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="33.8333">אולם קריאה</text>
            <text transform="matrix(-0.0012 0.8645 -1 -0.0014 519.0498 493.9395)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="33.8333">אולם השאלה</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tooltips are part of browser chrome, there's no way for a web page to affect either their look or position. You could of course roll your own and style them as you see fit using javascript and/or CSS but you'd need to use a different document structure (something that contained text or html elements).

Comment: I attempted to use divs and spans, but whenever I place a polygon in a div it no longer functions with the css.
How would you change the structure to accommodate the tooltip I need?

Comment: leave the polygon as it is, create a foreignObject sibling and put the text in a div in that.